# MySQL join unable to select from one table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a join that works exactly as expected, except any and all fields selected from the 'right' table are returned blank when they definitely are not.

```
SELECT score.recipient, score.amount, u.* FROM score 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON score.recipient = u.id AND u.team_id = ?
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(score.date) > ?
```

I don't actually need the entire users table, only users.email - but no fields work. The result set looks like this (sample):

```
[0] => stdClass Object ( [recipient] => 1 [amount] => 1 [id] => [fname] => [lname] => [nickname] => [email] => [phone] => [reg_key] => )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [recipient] => 103 [amount] => -1 [id] => [fname] => [lname] => [nickname] => [email] => [phone] => [reg_key] => )
```

All of the fields listed are in fact populated.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm at a loss.

Comment: what are you using for the SQL execution on PHP side? Looks like a PHP issue, not a MySQL one for me. Oh, and are you sure you need a LEFT join, not just a JOIN? That might be a issue, too.

Comment: Interesting - I'm using Codeigniter and its DB class, but the PHP itself is rather simple, pretty much just `$query = $this->db->query( $sql, array( $var1, $var2 ) )`. The result set is completely accurate other than the blank fields.

Comment: Oh, and regarding the JOIN type - I'm not sure. When I change it to just JOIN, though, the results set is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join condition / where clause is broken if replacing the left join with an inner join returns an empty result set.

Try this (without bind variables and their conditions) and see if it returns any values:

```
SELECT score.recipient, score.amount, u.* FROM score 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON score.recipient = u.id
```

If that's the case, then look at the values for team_id / score.date you get - I bet you're using a combination of bind values that simply does not exist in your tables.

Comment: Agree - your u.* values are empty because LEFT JOIN does not identify any "joinable" matches and returns NULL for u.* fields.

Comment: Ah, you were dead on. When I ran yours it proved that it was the bind values that were causing the problem. The values I was passing to team_id and score.date were null. Silly oversight on my end.